# Is it possible to customize the Outlook Conferencing Add in?

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to modify the labels of the outlook conferencing add in... e.g. I want to change the "Schedule a live meeting" text to say "Schedule my meeting". is it possible using VSTO? or I can create only new add ins using VSTO and not customize the existing ones ??

(I am talking abt this conferencing add in: http://aspoc.net/archives/2008/09/10/download-the-office-live-meeting-2007-client-and-conferencing-add-in-for-outlook/)

Answer (score 1):

ria,

You might be able to change the text I am not sure, I dont have 2007 installed to check but your vsto addin could search for the button control in the explorer command bars by ID or looping for the name etc. 
Then you could attempt to chaage the text of that button.

I will see if can find a 2007 VM to check for you.

Marcus